# how to correct the following linq?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following LINQ statement:

```
var inspectorAllocSummary = context
    .UserDetails
    .Where(ud => ud.PerformAudit == true && ud.Valid == true)
    .OrderBy(ud => ud.Firstname)
    .Select(ud
        => new InspectorWorkStatusModel
           {
               InspectorName = ud.Firstname,

               ToBeCompleted = context
                   .InspectorWorkAllocations
                   .Where(x => x.UploadCOESDetails.AuditMonth
                                   == criteria.AuditMonth 
                               && x.InspectorId == ud.Id)
                   .Sum(x=> x.ToBeAudited) ?? 0,

               Completed = context
                   .COESDetails
                   .Where(x => x.UploadCOESDetails.AuditMonth
                                   == criteria.AuditMonth 
                               && x.InspectorId == ud.Id
                               && x.AuditType != null)
                   .Count()
           });
```

The `ToBeCompleted` is an integer, it gets data from the database, but if it is null I want to make sure it is set to `0`. I tried the following:

```
ToBeCompleted = context
    .InspectorWorkAllocations
    .Where(x => x.UploadCOESDetails.AuditMonth == criteria.AuditMonth
                && x.InspectorId == ud.Id)
    .Sum(x=> x.ToBeAudited) ?? 0
```

but I get the following error:

> Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'int'

How can I ensure that if the return data is `null`, that it will be set to zero?

Comment: ToBeAudited is an Int.. plain old int

Comment: You should update the question with this information for it to be complete. Anyway, you can try my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ToBeAudited` is an `int` then `Sum` can never return `null`, it always returns an `int`.  If the collection is empty it will return 0.  just take off `?? 0`.

However, Linq-to-SQL and Linq-to-Entities *can* throw an error if the resultant SQL does not return any records.  For Linq-to-SQL one "fix" is to cast the underlying field to a nullable type:

```
.Sum(x=> (int?)x.ToBeAudited) ?? 0
```

For Linq-to-Entities a fix is to call `.DefaultIfEmpty()`:

```
.Select(x=> x.ToBeAudited)
.DefaultIfEmpty(0)
.Sum()
```

Comment: that's what I had originally, but I get the following error base {System.SystemException} = {"The cast to value type 'Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type."}

Comment: awesome, that works a treat.  I didn't know about defaultifempty.. thanks a bunch...

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to change the type of `ToBeAudited` to `int?`. The problem comes from the fact that `int` is a [value type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/s1ax56ch.aspx) and it cannot contain `null`. That's why in your first approach you get the error:

> The cast to value type 'Int32' failed because the materialized value is null.

There is a [`Sum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156065%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overload which accepts nullable values. So after changin `ToBeAudited` to nullable this will suffice:

```
ToBeCompleted = context
    .InspectorWorkAllocations
    .Where(x => x.UploadCOESDetails.AuditMonth == criteria.AuditMonth
                && x.InspectorId == ud.Id)
    .Sum(x => x.ToBeAudited).Value;
```

You don't need the `??` operator, as `null` values are being automatically ignored (and for the empty sequence `Sum` will return `0`).

Comment: thanks for that, but I am trying to fill my inspectorAllocSummary at the one time, rather than have different statements.. I have changed the ToBeAudited  field to a nullable int and used the following  context.InspectorWorkAllocations.Where(x => x.UploadCOESDetails.AuditMonth == criteria.AuditMonth && x.InspectorId == ud.Id).Sum(x=> x.ToBeAudited) ?? 0 and it works..  the issue is there are some records that don't exists.. so when it tried to find them it can't find them and returns null

Comment: @user2206329 Actually I was wrong about the `Sum`. See my update - you don't need the `??` operator.

Comment: that update doesn't work, i get the following error  Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @user2206329 Small mistake, sorry. Forgot to add `.Value` after `Sum`, as it returns nullable as well. It will never be `null` though. Now it should be fine.